# Where do I put the QT5 clone in this project

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

This is my first time every using C++ so please go easy on me.  I have about 7000 hours of Python experience so I'm not completely clueless.  I'm trying to read the code written for the Collatinus software found here. [collatinus](https://github.com/biblissima/collatinus).  It seems that the initial file is this:

```
VERSION = "11.2"

DEFINES += VERSION=\\\"$$VERSION\\\"
DEFINES += MEDIEVAL

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = collatinusd
INCLUDEPATH += . src
DEPENDPATH += .

DESTDIR = bin
OBJECTS_DIR= obj/
MOC_DIR = moc/
QMAKE_DISTCLEAN += $${DESTDIR}/collatinus

CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG += release_binary

QT += core
QT -= gui
QT          += xmlpatterns
QT += network
```

I've downloaded `qt` from [qt](http://www.qt.io/download) and got the open source qt5.  Now I cannot figure out where to put the file. I have tried putting it in the same folder as the above mentioned code.  I have also tried putting in the folder marked `src`.  In the `src` folder there are many files which use QT but it seems like the files are supposed to be taken out of the QT folder.  For example in [this](https://github.com/biblissima/collatinus/blob/master/src/flexion.cpp) file we have the syntax on line 28

```
#include <QDebug>
```

The QDebug file is in the QT folder.  But when I put the qt folder in either the topmost folder or the src folder I get the error message:

```
fatal error: 'QtCore' file not found
#include <QtCore>
```

So the file structure is as follows:

```
/collatinus-daemon
    collatinus.pro (and other files)
   //src
        flexion.cpp (and other files)
```

So where do I put the qt folder?  Also, I renamed it qt from qt5 since the syntax had the line:

```
QT += core
```

###################
Ok, I've got the QT creator up and running.  Here is the pro file

```
QT += network widgets
QT += core
QT -= gui

TARGET = Client_C11
VERSION = "1.0"
#CONFIG += console
#CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG += release_binary

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += src/client_main.cpp
OBJECTS_DIR= obj/
MOC_DIR = moc/
unix:!macx:DESTDIR = bin

macx:{
# Commandes spéciales pour déployer l'application sur Mac.
# J'ignore s'il faut l'équivalent pour Linux ou Windows.
# Philippe. Octobre 2016

QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.8
ICON = collatinus_bw.icns

deploy.commands = macdeployqt Client_C11.app
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += deploy

}
```

Here are some screenshots of my folders:

[image]
[image]
[image]

And here is the error message I'm getting:

[image]

Here also is the code for the client main

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtNetwork>

class QTcpSocket;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString req = "";
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        int i = 1;
        while (i < argc)
        {
            QString suite(argv[i]);
            req += " " + suite;
            i++;
        }
    }
    else req = "-?"; // pour afficher l'aide.

    QTcpSocket * tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket();
    tcpSocket->abort();
    tcpSocket->connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 5555);
    QByteArray ba = req.toUtf8();
    tcpSocket->write(ba);
    tcpSocket->waitForBytesWritten();
    tcpSocket->waitForReadyRead();
    ba = tcpSocket->readAll();
    tcpSocket->disconnectFromHost();
    tcpSocket->close();
    QString rep(ba);
    std::cout << rep.toStdString();

    a.quit();
}
```

I don't understand what I'm supposed to do with `qmake` and `cmakelists`

Comment: The "error message" you're getting is a warning. Just run the thing. Cmd-R. See what happens.

Comment: In the Qt Creator configuration of kits (`Cmd-\``, then Kits pane, Kits tab), select the kit you're using, make sure that the C and C++ compiler are from `/Library/Developer` etc. Most likely these compilers are already detected (see the Compilers tab), so you just need to choose them in that kit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where do I put the QT5 clone in this project

You don't :)

**Qt installations up to 5.14 are not relocatable**. That means that once Qt is installed, if you move it to another path, it'll break. Just don't mess with it: once installed, you leave it alone, and it'll work just fine.

Qt source code has to be built before it can be used. I presume that you downloaded the source code and want to stick it into the project and build the two that way. It's not designed to work that way at all.

Qt build requires several other tools to be installed (iirc python, ruby, perl), and other optional dependencies to get the full feature set, and if it fails for whatever reason, figuring it out is unnecessary effort initially. So it's best to start with pre-built Qt.

> I've downloaded qt from qt and got the open source qt5. Now I cannot figure out where to put the file.

Downloading "qt" doesn't mean much, since everyone means something else by that. If you've downloaded the source code, then delete it - last thing you want is to mess with compiling Qt right now.

Normally, Qt is installed using an installer, so what you'd download is an executable installer, and use that to select the Qt components you want to install. On Windows, pick the mingw-based Qt version, since that also installs the build environment (compilers) if you don't have them already. Otherwise you'd use the MSVC-based version if you got MSVC installed on Windows.

On Unix, you'd want to install Qt using the "native" package manager - one that came with your linux distribution, or macports (really preferred) on MacOS.

Once Qt is installed, you'd use Qt Creator IDE to open the collatinus project (its `.pro` file). And everything will "just work" from that point onwards - it'll let you build it and run whatever executable targets it produced. Of course you can build from the command line, but for a beginner it's just an extra layer of complication and unnecessary.

In any case, the `.pro` file you refer to would be processed by `qmake` to generate the build system that builds the project. `qmake` itself is the means you use to select what Qt version you build with: there's one `qmake` per each Qt installation. So, after `qmake` has ran, you'd `make` the thus-configured build, and there'll be no problems with finding Qt headers. It's the job of `qmake` in that case to set everything up so that the compiler will be told where to find Qt. You are not expected to have to mess with it manually.

If there's a `CMakeLists.txt` file in the project, you'd probably prefer to use that instead of `qmake`, since `cmake` is a widely used tool with lots of knowledge available online, whereas `qmake` is now obsolete. Still, older projects may only supply a `.pro` file that needs to be used with `qmake` and not `cmake`.

---

Your question doesn't nearly provide enough detail for a more focused answer - please tell us exactly what you did, and what Qt elements you installed (whether using Qt Installer program, or using a unix package manager).

Comment: Ok, well, I downloaded visual studios.  i'm pretty sure i already have qt downloaded on my mac.  i have to go to sleep now.  so i'll try to get the visual studios to work with the code tomorrow.

Comment: **Visual Studio is for Windows, not for Mac! Don't download it for Mac, it won't do you any good.** Remove Visual Studio for Mac, and make sure you've got XCode installed, then configure the compiler in Qt Creator's kits.